# How to count map size in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I have a map with key values as follows

```
$scope.items = {
  {
    0={"name": "Jim", "age" : 25}
  },
  {
    1={"name": "Eric", "age" : 25}
  }
};
```

if it was an array to count the size I with do:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items>
</div>
```

and have the size `{{items.length}}`

In case of a map I with iterate items as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="(id, item) in items">
</div>
```

but how to establish the size?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you fix your object structure? Right now it's not valid.

Comment: @dfsq sorry, I've edited.

Comment: Well it's still not valid javascript syntax. Looks like you indeed need an array: `$scope.items = [{"name": "Jim", "age" : 25}, {"name": "Eric", "age" : 25}]`. Or if this is an object then: `$scope.items = {0: {"name": "Jim", "age" : 25}, 1: {"name": "Eric", "age" : 25}}`.

Comment: Yes the second one. Basically a map (key, value).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One approach is to calculate number of keys in the object using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

```
$scope.itemsLength = Object.keys($scope.items).length;
```

you can also define a helper function:

```
$scope.getLength = function(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).length;
}
```

and use it in template:

```
{{ getLength(items) }}
```

Comment: But I need it on the page

Comment: It seems that this is the only way, since there is not function to call the map size.

Comment: I agree with your approach, but @Magini your model for array is very estrange... You should to try a default array using [ ... ].

Comment: @JoaozitoPolo I use this as (key, value) map and not array that's why :)

Answer (score 4):

I suggest to use a filter for this, which can be used across the application:

```
angular.module('filters').filter('objectKeysLength', [function() {
    return function(items) {
        return Object.keys(items).length;
    };
}]);
```

Then use it:

```
{{ items | objectKeysLength }}
```

or

```
<div ng-if="(items | objectKeysLength) > 0" >
    ...content...
</div>
```