# Count the number of objects in json array

Tags: angularjs, json

I'm using a GET method to view a json file as follows.

```
$scope.train = function () {

            var url = 'http://localhost/heart/api/restApiController/dataset.json';

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: url


            }).then(function (data) {

            });


        };
```

Now I want to count numberof objects in the json file.how can I do it?

**log of data**

```
Object {data: Array[5], status: 201, config: Object, statusText: "Created"}
config:Object
data:Array[5]
headers:(d)
status:201
statusText:"Created"
```

So there are 5 objects in this array.how can I get this value 5 from AngularJS code?

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28716541/how-to-count-map-size-in-angularjs and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5223/length-of-a-javascript-object-that-is-associative-array

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use the standard `length`

```
data.data.length
```

Comment: so if I want to count the objects with specific values, how can I do it?

Ex: I want to count the objects with weight: "2"

How to do this?

Comment: As you are using angularjs, you could use `filter` and then `length` on the returned array, see [filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)